# undefined control sequence when trying to define \gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{blue}{Male} in genealogytree

Tags: genealogytree

I get an error message when trying to compile a simple genealogy tree using template=symbol nodes

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{blue}{Male}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{red}{Female}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{black}{Neuter}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=symbol nodes]{
child{
gm pf cf
child{gm pf cf cm}
child{gm pf cm c- cm}
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives the error:

```
...
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected
                                {blue}{Male}
?
```

Comment: The error message suggests that haven't loaded the package that defines the macro `\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{blue}{Male}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{red}{Female}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{black}{Neuter}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=symbol nodes]{
child{
gm pf cf
child{gm pf cf cm}
child{gm pf cm c- cm}
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Another  code to get the same result**

```
\documentclass[
border=2mm,
convert={ density=600 -alpha Remove, outext=.png }
]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{blue}{Male}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{red}{Female}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{green}{Neuter}
\begin{genealogypicture}[template=symbol nodes]
child{
gm pf cf
child{gm pf cf cm}
child{gm pf cm c- cm}
}

\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]